# How can I add a custom "Date" field as a field in a view?

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I created a custom Content Type called "Event". In it, I use a custom "Date" field (from the Date module). When I try to create a View that displays all of the Events sorted by their Date, I can do this. However, when I try to add a *field* for "Date" so that I can display it in the output, "Date" is not shown in the list of fields. Is this because not all content types have a "Date" field? How can I get around this?

Comment: So you have a view that shows multiple content types and you wish to display a custom date field only on content of type event?  Or do you have a view of events that you want to display your custom date field on?

Comment: Do you have the date_views module enabled?

Comment: I have a problem with this too. Pre-existing content type with a date field and the field refuses to come up as an option. Seems to be working for some people so there must be something triggering this as a bug. My date is stored in ISO format, not sure if this would make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're having trouble.  I just did this and it worked.  Here's what I did.

1. Add a "Date" field (widget: select list) to Content Type A.
2. Create a view that shows items of Content Type A.
3. Click Add next to Fields and search for the label for my "Date" field.

You should try looking through/searching your list of fields again.  It should be there.  (Even when a view is filtered to a specific content type, the Views module will often allow you to select fields that are not associated with that content type.)